# SSRS matrix show hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, view, reporting-services, tree, hierarchy

I am working on a report where I have to display categories with a 6 level child hierarchy.

To put it more understandable:
Multiple categories, each of this categories has multiple attributes, each of these attributes can have multiple child attributes, these child attributes can have child attributes and so on.

The select statement result looks like:

```
ModellID | ModellName| ParentLevelID | LevelID | LevelName | ParentAttributeID | AttributeID | AttributeName
```

And the report should look like:

```
             Level 1       Level 2   Level 3   Level 4 ...
Modell A | Attribute A | Child A | Child A |         |
         |             |         | Child B | Child A |
         |             |         |         | Child B |
         |             | Child B | Child A |         |
         | Attribute B | Child A |         |         |
         | Attribute C | Child A | Child A |         |
         |             |         | Child B |         |
         |             |         | Child C |         |
         |             | Child B | Child A |         |
Modell B | Attribute A | Child A | Child A | Child A |
         |             |         |         | Child B |
```

I tried to make a matrix with Category as row group and level as column group with Attribute as value, but this shows only the first record for every category.

Also I tried multiple suggestions I found with the help of google, but I wasn't able to make them work.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Example Data:

```
Create Table hierarchy_ssrs (
    ModellID uniqueidentifier,
    ModellName varchar(max),
    ParentLevelID uniqueidentifier,
    LevelID uniqueidentifier,
    LevelName varchar(max),
    ParentAttributeID uniqueidentifier,
    AttributeID uniqueidentifier,
    AttributeName varchar(max)
)
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108638325/Example_Data.xlsx

You can import the data via SQL Management Studio.
Right click Database -> Tasks -> Import Data -> Data Source: MS Excel -> Browse File -> ... further steps should be self-explanatory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you supply a simplified example Dataset and your desired end result based on this to help demonstrate your requirements as well?

Comment: added an excel document with example data and the table definition. The end result should look like in the question with expand icons on each attribute and modell.

Comment: I'm sorry the file wasn't uploaded correctly, now the example data should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

For the dataset I used a select statement and joined the table with itself multiple times.
In the report builder I created a table using the select statement columns as columns in the table. Afterwards I created a row grouping for every column and deleted the corresponding old column.

This is the sql code for the select statement.

```
select hs1.ModellName as Modell, 
    hs1.AttributeName as [Level 1],
    hs2.AttributeName as [Level 2],
    hs3.AttributeName as [Level 3],
    hs4.AttributeName as [Level 4],
    hs5.AttributeName as [Level 5],
    hs6.AttributeName as [Level 6]
from hierarchy_ssrs hs1
    left join hierarchy_ssrs hs2 on hs2.ParentAttributeID = hs1.AttributeID
    left join hierarchy_ssrs hs3 on hs3.ParentAttributeID = hs2.AttributeID
    left join hierarchy_ssrs hs4 on hs4.ParentAttributeID = hs3.AttributeID
    left join hierarchy_ssrs hs5 on hs5.ParentAttributeID = hs4.AttributeID
    left join hierarchy_ssrs hs6 on hs6.ParentAttributeID = hs5.AttributeID
where hs.ParentAttributeID is null
order by Modell,
    LevelName,
    [Level 1],
    [Level 2],
    [Level 3],
    [Level 4],
    [Level 5],
    [Level 6]
```